# How to treat my custom emacs theme as a "safe theme"?

Tags: emacs

I'm using emacs 24 and [solarized](https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized) color theme.

When Emacs starts up, it prompt me with "Loading a theme can run Lisp code, really load?".

When I answer with "yes", it continues to "Treat this theme as safe in future sessions?".

If I say "y", the theme gets loaded, and

```
(custom-set-variables
    (custome-safe-themes (quote ("..." default))))
```

gets added to ~/.emacs automatically.

However, those questions come back every time I open Emacs!

What's the proper way to turn those off?

Comment: Is "..." really the string that gets written to your .emacs?

Comment: @pmr no, it's too long to type, it's some random alphanumerical string, I'm guessing it's a hashed result of some kind.

Comment: @DaNmarner If you answer the question a second time, are the strings different?

Comment: @pmr Just tried out...yes. That does explain it. But why? I didn't change the theme.

Comment: You may have a bug on your hands here. Try with other themes and then you might take it to the mailing-lists. Anyway, if you are new to emacs you might want to start with emacs23. I have a configuration that features zenburn/solarized in my github. https://github.com/bo0ts/.emacs

Comment: @pmr  This doesn't happen in Aquamacs nightly on my Mac. So maybe it's a Linux specific problem. I'll stick with Emacs 23 for now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If you use `M-x customize-themes` to set and save your preferred theme, then everything should work nicely.

If, instead, you've added code to your `.emacs` to enable the theme, but that code appears earlier in the file than the `custom-set-variables` command, then that might be the problem.

You can force Emacs to load a theme without prompting you to confirm its safety by using the `load-theme` function's `NO-CONFIRM` flag:

```
(load-theme 'solarized-light t)
```

Comment: customize-themes does not exist and the (load-theme 'color-theme-solarized-light t) says wrong number of arguments. Emacs24

Comment: Then you don't have Emacs 24, I'm afraid.

Comment: I was about to ridicule you, when, lo-and-behold, I apparently ran... Emacs23.  Good thing I checked that first. ;-)

Comment: LOL, glad you figured it out! :-)

Comment: Actually, I have now GNU Emacs 24.1.1, but it says:  Symbol's value as variable is void: n

Comment: (I also had to change the name from color-theme-solarized-light to solarized-light. The file is called solarized-light-theme.el

Comment: Good catch. There are several versions of the solarized theme, all with slightly different names.

Answer (score 5):

the same problem happened here. I solved this issue putting the custom-set-variables code before a load the theme.

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(custom-safe-themes (quote ("9527feeeec43970b1d725bdc04e97eb2b03b15be982ac50089ad223d3c6f2920" default))))
(custom-set-faces
)
```

Then I load my theme:

```
(defun use-default-theme()
  (load-theme 'default-black))

(use-default-theme)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i just removed the lines in .emacs and lo and behold the whole thing worked.

Answer (score 0):

After answering yes to those questions and starting emacs, remove or comment the lines containing the load-theme sentence. In my case those were:

(use-package doom-themes
:ensure t
:config
(load-theme 'doom-acario-dark))

If you don´t do that, emacs will ask again if you want to load the theme (which is already a safe one).